# What is the pythonic way to do a conditional count across pandas dataframe rows with apply?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I'm trying to do a conditional count across records in a pandas dataframe.  I'm new at Python and have a working solution using a for loop, but running this on a large dataframe with ~200k rows takes a long time and I believe there is a better way to do this by defining a function and using apply, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Here's a simple example.

Create a pandas dataframe with two columns:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'color': ['blue','green','yellow','blue','green','yellow','orange','purple','red','red'], 
        'weight': [4,5,6,4,1,3,9,8,4,1]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: df]

```
# for each row, count the number of other rows with the same color and a lesser weight
counts = []
for i in df.index:
    c = df.loc[i, 'color']
    w = df.loc[i, 'weight']
    
    ct = len(df.loc[(df['color']==c) & (df['weight']<w)])
    counts.append(ct)

df['counts, same color & less weight'] = counts
```

[image: df updated]

For each record, the 'counts, same color & less weight' column is intended to get a count of the other records in the df with the same color and a lesser weight.  For example, the result for row 0 (blue, 4) is zero because no other records with color=='blue' have lesser weight.  The result for row 1 (green, 5) is 1 because row 4 is also color=='green' but weight==1.

How do I define a function that can be applied to the dataframe to achieve the same?

I'm familiar with apply, for example to square the weight column I'd use:

```
df['weight squared'] = df['weight'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
```

... but I'm unclear how to use apply to do a conditional calculation that refers to the entire df.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `transform` with `min` `groupby`

```
df.weight.gt(df.groupby('color').weight.transform('min')).astype(int)
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    1
9    0
Name: weight, dtype: int64
#df['c...]=df.weight.gt(df.groupby('color').weight.transform('min')).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S, I'm working through understanding this.  A use case that I need to accommodate is that if there are multiple other records with the same color and lesser weight, I need to count both.  For example, if row 10 is ('green', 2), then I need our calculated column for row 1 to return 2 as it'd be counting rows 4 and 10.  Can your solution be adjusted to achieve this?

Comment: @jdscott df.weight.gt(df.groupby('color').weight.transform('min')).astype(int).\
...     groupby(df.color).transform('sum')

Comment: Thanks again.  With that addition the result I get for row 4 ('green', 1) is 2 but should be zero as there are no rows with values ('green', 0).  Same issue with rows 5 and 9.  Any ideas?